# Laravel - Dynamically Building Routes From Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, model

I'm trying to build routes from a model below is the code.

```
$data = \App\Models\ModelName::all();

    if(!empty($data) && $data->count() >= 1)
    {
        foreach($data as $d)
        {
            Route::prefix('/'.$d['data_field'])->name($d['data_field'])->group(function(){
                Route::get('/', ucfirst($d['data_field']).'Controller@index');                  
            });
        }
    }
```

I kept getting the error message that $d is not defined. Is there a way to build the routes dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$d` into the closure, as it doesn't exist within the scope of the anonymous function:

```
Route::prefix('/'.$d['data_field'])
    ->name($d['data_field'])->group(function() use ($d) {
           Route::get('/', ucfirst($d['data_field']).'Controller@index');                  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. perfect answer